# Updating user information in SQL

Tags: beginner, sql, go, postgresql

Newbie here. I have this `gqlgen` api with `sqlc` update code, which updates the user by given id with provided fields:

```golang
// graph/schema.resolvers.go

...

func (r *mutationResolver) UserUpdate(ctx context.Context, id string, input model.EditUser) (bool, error) {
    // Validate
    v := validator.New()
    if err := v.Struct(input); err != nil {
        for _, err := range err.(validator.ValidationErrors) {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        return false, errors.New(err.Error())
    }
    pg := db.ConnectPg()
    defer pg.Close()
    // Parse string id to int64
    parsedId, _ := strconv.ParseInt(id, 10, 64)
    u := db.User{}
    var err error
    // GetUserById is generated by sqlc
    if u, err = db.NewPg(pg).GetUserById(ctx, parsedId); err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    // Confirm ownership or admin
    user := auth.ForContext(ctx)
    if user != nil || user.ID == parsedId || user.IsAdmin {
        if input.EmailVerified != nil {
            u.EmailVerified = *input.EmailVerified
        }
        if input.MobileVerified != nil {
            u.MobileVerified = *input.MobileVerified
        }
        if input.IsActive != nil {
            u.IsActive = *input.IsActive
        }
        if input.Name != nil {
            u.Name = sql.NullString{String: *input.Name, Valid: true}
        }
        if input.Avatar != nil {
            u.Name = sql.NullString{String: *input.Avatar, Valid: true}
        }
        if input.Email != nil {
            u.Email = sql.NullString{String: *input.Email, Valid: true}
        }
        if input.Mobile != nil {
            u.Mobile = sql.NullString{String: *input.Mobile, Valid: true}
        }
        if input.Password != nil {
            bytes, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(*input.Password), 14)
            hashedPassword := string(bytes)
            u.Password = hashedPassword
        }
        if input.IsAdmin != nil {
            if user.IsAdmin {
                u.IsAdmin = *input.IsAdmin
            } else {
                return false, fmt.Errorf("Access denied")
            }
        }
        // UpdateUser and UpdateUserParams are generated by sqlc
        if _, err := db.NewPg(pg).UpdateUser(ctx, db.UpdateUserParams{
            ID:             u.ID,
            Name:           u.Name,
            Avatar:         u.Avatar,
            Email:          u.Email,
            EmailVerified:  u.EmailVerified,
            Mobile:         u.Mobile,
            MobileVerified: u.MobileVerified,
            Password:       u.Password,
            IsAdmin:        u.IsAdmin,
            IsActive:       u.IsActive,
            UpdatedAt:      time.Now(),
        }); err != nil {
            return false, err
        }
        return true, nil
    }
    return false, fmt.Errorf("Access denied")
}

...
```

And it is working correctly. However coming from Node land, I feel like it is too verbose. Or is this just how Golang does it? What if I have like more than 10 columns, do I have to check `nil` for each of them?

I tried searching some Golang tutorials but couldn't find much out there like Node. How would an experienced Gopher write this code in neat?

---

Other information you may need.

This is `EditUser` struct "generated" by `gqlgen` but can be edited:

```golang
// graph/models/user.go

type EditUser struct {
    Name           *string `json:"name,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,max=100"`
    Avatar         *string `json:"avatar,omitempty"`
    Email          *string `json:"email,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,email"`
    EmailVerified  *bool   `json:"emailVerified,omitempty"`
    Mobile         *string `json:"mobile,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,min=2,max=55"`
    MobileVerified *bool   `json:"mobileVerified,omitempty"`
    Password       *string `json:"password,omitempty"`
    IsAdmin        *bool   `json:"is_admin,omitempty"`
    IsActive       *bool   `json:"isActive,omitempty"`
}
```

This is `User` struct "generated" by `sqlc`:

```
// db/models.go
// Code generated by sqlc. DO NOT EDIT.

package db

type User struct {
    ID             int64          `json:"id"`
    Name           sql.NullString `json:"name"`
    Avatar         sql.NullString `json:"avatar"`
    Email          sql.NullString `json:"email"`
    EmailVerified  bool           `json:"email_verified"`
    Mobile         sql.NullString `json:"mobile"`
    MobileVerified bool           `json:"mobile_verified"`
    // is required
    Password   string         `json:"password"`
    IsAdmin    bool           `json:"is_admin"`
    IsActive   bool           `json:"is_active"`
    CreatedAt  time.Time      `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt  time.Time      `json:"updated_at"`
    LastSignin sql.NullTime   `json:"last_signin"`
}
```

This is `UpdateUserParams` "genearted" by `sqlc`:

```golang
// db/user.sql.go
// Code generated by sqlc. DO NOT EDIT.
// source: user.sql

type UpdateUserParams struct {
    ID             int64          `json:"id"`
    Name           sql.NullString `json:"name"`
    Avatar         sql.NullString `json:"avatar"`
    Email          sql.NullString `json:"email"`
    EmailVerified  bool           `json:"email_verified"`
    Mobile         sql.NullString `json:"mobile"`
    MobileVerified bool           `json:"mobile_verified"`
    Password       string         `json:"password"`
    IsAdmin        bool           `json:"is_admin"`
    IsActive       bool           `json:"is_active"`
    UpdatedAt      time.Time      `json:"updated_at"`
}
```

---

go (v1.15), sqlc (v1.5.0), gqlgen (v0.13.0)

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `if input.Avatar != nil { u.Name = sql.NullString{…` I hope you have unit tests in place. And yes, this is not the way to code this, me not knowing how to in Go notwithstanding.